# how to use SQL Script in android?

Tags: android, android-studio, sql-scripts

[image]
 there are many thing in android studio we don't know or don't use its features ,how to user this feature? **sql script**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i got ans
The script is located at  *assert*  folder -scripts developed by  SQL Developer

```
InputStream is = getResources().getAssets().open("SQLScript.sql");
String sql= convertStreamToString(is);

public static String convertStreamToString(InputStream is)
            throws IOException {
            Writer writer = new StringWriter();
        char[] buffer = new char[2048];
        try {
            Reader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,
                    "UTF-8"));
            int n;
            while ((n = reader.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                writer.write(buffer, 0, n);
            }
        } finally {
            is.close();
        }
        String text = writer.toString();
        return text;
}


SQLiteDatabase db;
db = openOrCreateDatabase("MyDatabase.db", SQLiteDatabase.CREATE_IF_NECESSARY, null );
db.execSQL(sql);
```